# RichTextBox: Transparent Background vs. Font Quality in Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I created a RTF control pretty similar to the one described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms996492.aspx).
Works pretty fine. Sometimes i have the control draw its contents directly to the device context, sometimes i use an offscreen bitmap which i draw to the device context myself, depending on the situation.

Now i needed the control to have a transparent background so i've overriden the `CreateParams` method called on initalising the base clss and added `createParams.ExStyle |= 0x20;` which boils down to one of the extended window styles, WS_EX_TRANSPARENT.

At this point, transparency works like a charm. But in contrast to before, setting this option makes drawing to the offscreen bitmap unusable, since the font quality suffers. Note, that only when drawing to the bitmap the font quality turns bad, drawing to the device context of the control is still working although creating the offscreen bitmap uses the same routines, just with a different device context.

[image: Output comparison: Control on the left; Bitmap on the right.]

As you can see, the font on the left is perfectly fine, while on the right side, the font get messy, too bold and it seems like it's drawn over several times with the coordinates not matching.

Commenting out the line added for transparency makes the bitmap return to normal but also yields in a white background for everything drawn, making me loose transparency.

Any ideas how to get a successfull combination of the two desired effects?

Comment: It is the basic reason why controls are opaque by design.  As long as monitors are not yet approaching the kind of DPI that a printer supports (600 dots-per-inch), using anti-aliasing is pretty crucial to create good looking text.  ClearType is the usual default.  Anti-aliasing can only ever work correctly if the text is drawn on a known background.  And it never is for a transparent window.  Right now it anti-aliases from black to black, that is why it looks fat.  There is no fix for this, an opaque background is required.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for the information. I thought it looked like Anti-Aliasing failed, but couldn't think of a reason why just adding one line would turn off AA. Do you have a clue on how to disable the transparent background temporary for drawing to the Bitmap context? CreateParams is just called during the constructor. Would i have to create an additional instance without the transparent style?